# onclick and ng-click event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I am working with Onsen UI (angularjs) + Cordova and I have this problem:
I have a button that is not working right now, but this button was working sometime ago. Now I cannot even get click event of the button.
Does somebody know what is the problem?

HTML:

```
<ons-list id="list-actions" style="border-top: none"><ons-list-item style="line-height: 1; padding: 0;">
        <ons-row class="action">
          <ons-col class="bt-pres action-col col {{interaction[0].present}}">
            <div class="action-icon"><ons-icon icon="ion-fireball"></ons-icon></div>
            <div class="action-label">Press</div>
          </ons-col>
```

Javascript:

```
  //not working
  $(document).on("click",".bt-pres",function(){
    alert("clicked");
```

Comment: is your event registered under `document.ready()` function?

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry short code.

Comment: So, your code worked some time before?

Comment: Yes It was working. I don't know why It cannot gets click event now

Comment: could you please unbind your click event before registering click event. `$('body').off('click','.bt-pres');`

Comment: Yes, I've tried it too. $(elem).off.on("click",...); but had no success

Comment: where are you placing your script? is it within your html file or separate js file?

Comment: It is inside the HTML file at the end of document

Comment: k. place it inside your `<head></head>` and add a break point to your event registering line. You can use keyword `debugger;` just above `$('body').off('click','.bt-pres');`. So, we can check that whether it is registering or not?

Comment: Have you tried to fire the event when the `ons-list-item` element has been clicked? I think you are trying to fire it in the wrong element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your replies. Looking the code again and over again, my bad was I had twice codes like `$(document).on('click', elem, func)` and it was in conflict. Then I changed this to use angular ngclick function inside controller. This worked like a charm. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

First of all `alert()` is not working in neither ripple nor device (as per my knowledge). If you want to trigger the function i suggest `ng-click()`

example 
HTML

```
<div ng-controller="LoginController">
   <ons-button ng-click="Login()">Login</ons-button>
</div>
```

JS

```
.controller('LoginController', function () {
   $scope.Login = function () {
      console.log("triggered");
   }
}
```

in your case try the bellow code

```
$(document).on("click","div.action-label",function(){
    console.log("triggered");
}
```

Comment: As I've said in title, I already tried ng-click and not working too. Your solution not worked for me. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: did you add your angular module before the `.controller` ?? 
`var myApp = angular.module('app', ['onsen', 'ngMessages']);`

`myApp .controller('LoginController', function () {}`